# laravel 4 - how output distinct values of relation

Tags: php, laravel, collections, laravel-4, distinct

I have this pivot table:
Entitystandpoints
id - event_id - question_id - entity_id - standpoint_value
The entities participate in events and and by the participation they reveal they standpoint for a question.

The question 12 is "do you like blue color?"

and the question 11 is "do you like red color?

The event "1" is "Please name a color which you like or dislike"

A simplified case of three records:

```
id - event_id - question_id - entity_id - standpoint_value
1 - 1 - 12 - 101 - 1
2 - 1 - 12 - 102 - 0 
3 - 1 - 11 - 103 - 1
```

So entities 101 and 102 answer to the question 12, and the entity 103 answers to question 11

What I want to do: 
I want to create relation which would list all questions answered in an event, but I want to print DISTINCT questions, without repeating them - in this case the question 12 would be printed twice.

I defined this relation in my Model named Event1:

```
public function question_byrel()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Entitystandpoint', 'event_id');
}
```

but when I make a *foreach* loop like this:

```
@foreach ($object->question_byrel->unique() as $rq) 
....
@endforeach
```

it would list all occurences of a question. And I want 
is the question no. 12 to be printed only once.
The unique() doesn't work,  it at least won't crash the view.
How tell L4 which column should be treated as "distinct"? 
unique('column_name') doesn't work either.

**If anyone cares to give an advanced advice:** in the final version i'd be happy to list all DISCTINCT questions, but additionally, in case that more than one entity answers the same question, I'd like to enumerate them within one cycle of the above loop. 
I'd be enough happy just to print number of entities, it listing them would be troublesome.

Thx

Comment: Check your code again, as this would not return duplicates of Eloquent models.

Comment: no, the code is not working - it cannot, as far as I udenrstand the code, it does not inform Laravel, that I want to make "question_id" distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make `Eloquent\Collection` items unique by a property other than `primary key`, then do this:

```
@foreach ($object->question_byrel->keyBy('question_id') as $rq)
```